# Hide React button after it is clicked

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a checklist of questions set up where I check if one of the checkboxes is selected I will show the first button. If no checkbox is selected I show the second "Submit" button. When a user clicks submit a messages shows up inside . What I also want to do for the UI, doesn't have to functionally submit at this point but would be great if it does is to hide the actual Submit button as soon as the  button is shown.

So once the Submit button is clicked I want it to disappear off the screen.

Logic to see if the default **submit button** or second **Continue button** should be displayed:

```js
const decideIfButtonShouldBeShown = (checked) => {
  const answeredQuestion = data.questions.some(
    (q) => q.answer === true
  );
  if (answeredQuestion)
    setShowButton(true);
  else
    setShowButton(false);
}


const showOptionCardDisplay = () => {
  setShowOption(logic.displayOption(data));
};
```

This is the button:

```js
{
  showButton ?
    <IonButton
      size="large"
      color="secondary"
      expand="full"
      routerLink={'/newpage'}>
      Contiunue
              <IonIcon slot="end" icon={arrowForward} />
    </IonButton>
    :
    <IonButton
      size="large"
      color="primary"
      expand="full"
      onClick={() => {
        showOptionCardDisplay();
      }}
    >
      Submit
    </IonButton>
}
```

Comment: Code seems fine , what is not working?

Comment: @Itamar Code is okay, it is an additional hide of the Submit button once that has been clicked. Otherwise, code is working correctly. So I want to hide the submit button once clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your expectation, you want to show your `Contiunue` button if there is at least one checked checkbox (one `true` in your answers).

Altough achieving this, would be as easy as:

```
const showButton = data.questions.some((q) => q.answer);

{showButton ? (
    <IonButton
        size="large"
        color="secondary"
        expand="full"
        routerLink={'/newpage'}
    >
        Contiunue
        <IonIcon slot="end" icon={arrowForward} />
     </IonButton>
    ) : (
    <IonButton
        size="large"
        color="primary"
        expand="full"
        onClick={() => showOptionCardDisplay()}
     >
        Submit
    </IonButton>
)}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, you would like to hide the Submit button too if it has been clicked.

The next solution would separate the logic for showing the second button, and it is set to `false` in `showOptionCardDisplay`. So basically you can control your first button visibility with  `decideIfButtonShouldBeShown` and if the first button is not visible, then the second button can be shown conditionally.

```
const [showSubmitButton, setShowSubmitButton] = useState(true);
const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(false);

const decideIfButtonShouldBeShown = (checked) => {
    const answeredQuestion = data.questions.some((q) => q.answer);

    if(answeredQuestion) {
      setShowButton(true);
    } else {
      setShowButton(false);
    }
}

const showOptionCardDisplay = () => {
  setShowOption(logic.displayOption(data));
  setShowSubmitButton(false);
};

{showButton ? (
    <IonButton
        size="large"
        color="secondary"
        expand="full"
        routerLink={'/newpage'}
    >
        Contiunue
        <IonIcon slot="end" icon={arrowForward} />
     </IonButton>
) : null}

{!showButton && showSubmitButton ? (
    <IonButton
        size="large"
        color="primary"
        expand="full"
        onClick={() => showOptionCardDisplay()}
     >
        Submit
    </IonButton>
) : null}
```

Comment: Code is okay, it is an additional hide of the Submit button once that has been clicked. I just don't know where to add that condition based on how this is set up. I.e. Clicking Submit shows the message and hides the Submit button. User should no longer see the submit button

Comment: Based on your comment, I've edited my answer, please let me know if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
if(answeredQuestion )
      setshowButton(true);
    else
      setshowButton(false);
```

You wrote either set variable name in wrong there or wrong in here -  **showButton ?**

I mean check character lower case issue in showButton name.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for answers, Ive used this info to create play/pause button

```
const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
const play = () => { 
    if (playing == true){
      // stop and start again
      player.playbackManager.pause(); 
      setPlaying(false);
    }else{
      // play 
      player.playbackManager.play();
      setPlaying(true);
    }
  };


  return (
   <div>
   <div className="controller-bar"> 
        <IonButton component="span" onClick={play}>
           
 {playing ? ( <PlayArrow />  ) : (   <Pause/> )}
        </IonButton> 
  </div>
  );
}
```